# How can I switch sheet focus in Numbers using JXA?

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation, apple-numbers

I am working on a JXA script that will be used to copy tables from an existing Numbers sheet, and then paste them into a newly created sheet (in the same document) before making some modifications to individual cell values. I have most of what I need working, but have been unable to figure out how to change the active sheet from the source sheet to the destination sheet (or any sheet).

I have tried the following;

`Numbers.documents[0].sheets.byName({name: currentSheet}).activate`

It seems to execute (there are no errors), but nothing happens in Numbers. The active sheet does not change. I have the script working in AppleScript using

`set active sheet to sheet currentSheet`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
var numbersApp = Application("Numbers");
var docNumbers = numbersApp.documents[0]

// First sheet
docNumbers.activeSheet.set(docNumbers.sheets[0])

// Using sheet name
docNumbers.activeSheet.set(docNumbers.sheets["sheetName"])
```

Comment: Yes, this does what I needed. Thanks!